# GeoDjango: Geographic query causes segmentation fault

Tags: django, segmentation-fault, geodjango, spatialite, django-dev-server

On Django development server with SpatiaLite, I am trying to do a basic geographic query:

```
Location.objects.filter(geom__within=loc.geom)
```

This causes a `Segmentation error` and the server dies. `loc` is an instance of the `Location` model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    geom = models.GeometryField()

    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

What do you think might be wrong?

Comment: Debugging through the lens of a web browser is a PITA. Try running this from a standalone script. If it still manifests, then you can run it under pdb (or debugger of choice) and dig a little more deeply.

Comment: Thanks. The stack trace does not tell much either. This may be an incompatibility with the installed libraries. I will check on other configurations and update the question.

Comment: it might be related to this: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/geos-devel/2011-September/005419.html but still not resolved :(